# starting IE9 via vboxmanage guestcontrol can't access localstorage

Tags: internet-explorer-9, local-storage, virtualbox, karma-runner

We use a VirtualBox WinVista VM for testing our JavaScript app in IE9 (and other Windows browsers). As a test runner, we use Karma. Through the Karma github we located a bash script that launches IE9 and starts the test runner in that browser.

This works, for the biggest part, but when we want to use localStorage we get an "Access is denied" error. However, when we start the browser manually in the VM, we can access localStorage without any problem.

It seems that starting the browser via the VBoxManage guestcontrol command does something with the user rights that prevents the browser from accessing the localStorage directory on the hard disk. Of course, we're using the same user account for VboxManage and running the browser by hand.

Chrome also displayed the same issue, but we could redirect it to the public directory. We've tried changing the registry entry that points to the IE9 localstorage directory, but that doesn't seem to work.

If we can't figure this out, we'll have to fall back to our previous solution, using Selenium WebDriver to run the tests, making Karma less useful.

Comment: Are you able to list the bash script or where you found it?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost entirely the exact same problem (if not exactly). After pulling out my hair trying to use runas.exe to load IE as the correct user, which fixed the localStorage issue, it alas didn't allow karma to connect properly.

It turns out that the latest VirtualBox (at the time, 4.3) with the 4.3 version of the guest addition makes the VBoxManage command load IE with the correct user and therefore the rights to access localStorage.

The code I used in the shell script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
CAPTUREURL=$1

VMNAME="IE9 - Win7"
LOGIN="IEUser"
PASSWORD="Passw0rd!"
SNAPSHOTNAME="Guest2"

VBoxManage snapshot "$VMNAME" restore "$SNAPSHOTNAME"

VBoxManage startvm "$VMNAME"

# Kill iexplore if it's already open
VBoxManage guestcontrol "$VMNAME" execute \
  --username "$LOGIN" \
  --password "$PASSWORD" \
  --image "C:\\Windows\\System32\\TaskKill.exe" \
  --verbose \
  --wait-stdout -- "/IM" "iexplore.exe" "/F"

# Wait for network to start up
sleep 10 # Can this be done in a better way?

VBoxManage guestcontrol "$VMNAME" execute \
  --username "$LOGIN" \
  --password "$PASSWORD" \
  --image "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe" \
  --verbose \
  -- "${CAPTUREURL/localhost/10.0.2.2}"

# Allow IE to boot up and connect before letting the script start
sleep 3
```

To re-iterate and make more clear, VBoxManage for versions < 4.3 were loading the browsers with the wrong user, one that did not have the permissions needed for localstorage.